# Creating directories from a CSV file and getting just one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, directory

I explain briefly what I did until the misfunction:
A CSV file is read and divided into 2 different ones depending on the value of a column.
The column refers to the type of food and the category 'carne' is divided into other difference.
That's why I decided to divided into 2 CSV files. These CSV Files contain a single column.

Now I want to create some directories related to these 2 CSV files:

1. Other categories: includes fish, salad, eggs...
2. Carne: includes different types of meat, which will need to be in a sub-directory in Meat

This is how carne.csv looks like:

```
            0
0     carnero
1         ave
2     ternera
3       anade
4     cabrito
5       capon
6     caracol
```

The categories should be ordered like this:

```
Salad
Fish
...
Meat
    Chicken
    Beef
    ....
```

The code I wrote is to set these two types of directories is:

```
other_categories = pd.read_csv('other_categories.csv')
baseDir = "data/"
for category in other_categories:
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(baseDir,category))
    
carne = pd.read_csv ('carne.csv')
baseDir_carne = "data/carne/"
for category in carne:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(baseDir_carne,category))
```

Looking at the directory it was created only 1 folder and the name is `'0'`.

Why is this happening? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using pandas to parse the CSV table, which creates a DataFrame.

> Read a comma-separated values (csv) file into DataFrame.
> [pandas API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)
> [pandas DataFrame API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

This means that you can not use the standard for each method, as DataFrame is not a simple collection. So this part can not work as intended:

```
for category in other_categories:
```

In order to iterate over the items, I would recommend to use one of the build-in methods, such as *itertuples*.

[itertuples panda API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples)

A small example. Assuming x is your CSV file parsed into the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([["carnero"],["ave"],["ternera"]])

for cat in x.itertuples():
    print(cat)
```

It will print the following tuples:

> Pandas(Index=0, _1='carnero')

> Pandas(Index=1, _1='ave')

> Pandas(Index=2, _1='ternera')

You can now access the tuple regularly, for example, replacing `print(cat)` with `print(cat[1])` to access the second tuple element, will return the string.

Transfering this knowledge over to your code, the for each should look something along these lines:

```
for category in carne.itertuples():
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(baseDir_carne,category[1]))
```

I hope this clears up your question, feel free to ask if there is something you are missing.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you for the information but I don't understand what you mean. This wont create directories. This will only create tuples and I'm not interested on it.

Comment: You try to access a DataFrame like a collection, but this does not work. You need to use one of the provided methods. itertuples() provides you a tuple of the row, so you can now actually access the data within the DataFrame.

Comment: I can not edit my previous comment, so here is another: You need to create the tuples to actually access the data from the DataFrame. I added an example to my answer with your code, you need to apply this to both of your for each loops.

Comment: OK I finally understood. I tried it, but some Error appears. ````[Errno 17] File exists: '/home/datasci/prog_datasci_2/activities/activity_2/salsas'```` The folder doesn't exist. It is created when using the 'for' loop. Do you know why?

Comment: There could be a couple of reasons. The most simple one: are you checking the correct folder? I tried the code but it seems to work just fine. However, if you changed the path from `baseDir = "data/"` to `baseDir = "/data/"` it will create the folders in different locations, for example in `C:/data/` if you are working with Windows instead of the folder where the script is located.